# Как избежать дублирования кода в методе при проверке форм на заполненность в Java GUI?

Tags: java

У меня две переключающиеся друг на друга формы с взаимной передачей данных между собой. Нужно проверить их на заполненность перед переключением.

Как избавиться от дублирования строк проверки и какой метод для этого нужно выделить?

```
private void setSwitchingFromForm1(Person person) {

    if (person.getSurname().isEmpty()) {
        showOptionPaneWarningSurname();
    }
    else if (person.getFirstName().isEmpty()) {
        showOptionPaneWarningFirstName();
    }
    else if (person.getLastName().isEmpty()) {
        int confirm = customizeOptionDialog();
        if (confirm == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
            setContentPanel(form2.getRootPanel());
            form2.setPerson(person);
        }
    }
    else {
        setContentPanel(form2.getRootPanel());
        form2.setPerson(person);
    }
}

private void setSwitchingFromForm2(Person person) {

    if(person.getSurname().isEmpty()) {
        showOptionPaneWarningSurname();
    }
    else if(person.getFirstName().isEmpty()) {
        showOptionPaneWarningFirstName();
    }
    else if(person.getLastName().isEmpty()) {
         int confirm = customizeOptionDialog();
        if (confirm == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
            setContentPanel(form1.getRootPanel());
            form1.setPerson(person);
        }
    }
    else {
        setContentPanel(form1.getRootPanel());
        form1.setPerson(person);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Может передавать формы как параметры в метод?

А сам метод поднять в родительский/абстрактный класс на уровень выше? 
(или как там вам удобнее по структуре вашего проекта...)

А по месту использовать указывая нужные формы как параметры?

```
 private void setSwitchingFromForm2(Person person,Form form1,Form form2)
```

---

P.S.

Может показаться что у вас там ошибка:
в обоих методах строка

```
form2.setPerson(person);
```

может быть в первом методе должно быть **form1**.setPerson(person); ?

Comment: а да, копипастнул не глядя, точнее во втором методе form1.setPerson(person); - передача данных обратно в первую форму...

Comment: Спасибо огромное, Ваши размышления помогли, добавил в параметр setSwitchingFromForm (Person person, Container panel) - всё заработало!

Comment: @Ompro тогда можете проголосовать за ответ и выбрать его как правильный (**поставив галочку**) так здесь принято вот подробнее: [Что это означает, если ответ «принят»?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Comment: Ок, поставил, спасибо!!!